# How to get text content of elements in a div onClick? React.js, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to get the text content of the div, on click.

I have tried to add ref's to my syntax but it doesn't work when I try to do `const ref = this.refName.textContent`.

So what I would like to achieve is on click of `recipe-container`, store the text content of the `h3` and `ul` into variables, where the variable are in a parent component.

This is my child component here:

```
export default class Recipecontainer extends React.Component {
render(){
    const recipe = this.props.recipe;
    let recipeIngredients = recipe.ingredients;
    recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>);
    return (
        <div className="recipe-container">
            <h3 className="recipe-name">{recipe.recipeName}</h3>
            <div className="food-img">
                <img src={recipe.smallImageUrls} alt=""/>
            </div>
            <ul className="ingredient-list">{recipeIngredients}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And this is the method that I would plan to use, which is in my parent component, to save these text content into variables; but of course what i have written below does not work.

```
saveData(e){
    const recipeName = document.getElementsByClassName(".recipe-name").textContent;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(".recipe-name").innerHTML` to get the value.

Comment: why don't you pass a callback into Recipecontainer then handle onClick of the outer div and call the callback with values from this.props.recipeName and recipeIngredients? or am I missing something

Comment: would you be able to show an example ? Sorry, am still new to React!

Answer (score 1):

instead of **`textCOntent`** use **`innerHTML`**

```
 const recipeName = document.getElementsByClassName(".recipe-name").innerHTML;
```

Comment: unfortunately, this returns me undefined

Comment: console.log(document.getElementsByClassName(".recipe-name")) and see

Comment: I guess you might be referring to `document.getElementsByClassName("recipe-name")`  without the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the html itself, You need to pass **smallImageUrls** & **smallImageUrls** to parent component when user click the div so Use the react way:

```
<div className="recipe-container" onClick={() => this.props.onDivClick(recipe.recipeName, recipe.smallImageUrls)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this;

```
<div className="recipe-container" onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.textContent)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `onClick` callback to your `props`, and use that to callback , with the recipe data, when the `<div>` is clicked in the child component. Like so:

```
export default class Recipecontainer extends React.Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    const { onClick, recipe: { recipeName, recipeIngredients } } = this.props;
    recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients.map((item, index) => ( index, item ));
    onClick({ recipeName, recipeIngredients });
  }
  render(){
      const recipe = this.props.recipe;
      let recipeIngredients = recipe.ingredients;
      recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>);
      return (
          <div className="recipe-container" onClick={this.handleClick} >
              <h3 className="recipe-name">{recipe.recipeName}</h3>
              <div className="food-img">
                  <img src={recipe.smallImageUrls} alt=""/>
              </div>
              <ul className="ingredient-list">{recipeIngredients}</ul>
          </div>
      )
  }
```

If you absolutely need access to the DOM element of the child (I really don't think you do), the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) recommends a callback prop attached to the DOM as a ref attribute, like so:

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={props.inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CustomTextInput
        inputRef={el => this.inputElement = el}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
$('#here').bind('click', function(event) {
  this.toggleModal.bind(this, items.base_image, items.product_name, items.base_price);
});

function toggleModal(image, name, price) {
  console.log(image);
  console.log(name);
  console.log(price);
  const popupimage = image;
  console.log(popupimage);
  this.setState({
    showModal: !this.state.showModal
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className={styles.product_cart} key={index} id="here"></div>
```

It will work for me try to pass all the values what you need in function ....